# Handling MediaPlayer error when SDCard removed

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-sdcard, android-external-storage

I want to handle use case when user remove SD Card while Android MediaPlayer is playing song.
I was trying to do it in `BroadcastReciever` and listen to `ACTION_MEDIA_REMOVED` or other actions related with SD.
I always get errors.
In receiver I was calling player.reset(); to get to idle status. After calling that method my media player stuck in infinite loop with errors printing in logcat.
How can I manage that UC? Can I use [OnErrorListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.html)?

I'm using Thread to publish progress of song playback on UI, I'm killing it before resetting player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [description](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#asyncerror) of how to handle errors when using MediaPlayer. You should use `OnErrorListener`. It will put MediaPlayer into error state (see [this state diagram](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)). To exit from this state you need to `reset()` the player.